# Rendering differences in chrome 26.0.1410.43 from older versions

Tags: google-chrome, rendering, css

My website was working properly in firefox opera and chrome (I don't have IE so I am not sure about that-since I am using fedora linux 18). After a recent update of chrome(at most a month old) the page was not rendering correctly.Does anybody know what changed? I am suspecting that something changed in the way the box model is interpreted because I am using display:table-cell  in this way:

```
 <div id="midboxmidleft" style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;">
          <div id="sideleft">
          <ul>
          <li>blahblah</li>
          <li>blahblah</li>
          <li>blahblah</li>
          <li>blahblah</li>
          <li>bla blah</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

...Same on the right 
(in order to achieve vertical centering)

I also because some of the awkwardness happens on mouse over I want to mention that I am using this css as well:

```
li :hover{background-color:#fff;-moz-opacity:.500;filter:alpha(opacity=50);opacity:.50;}
```

The markup was validated successfully. 
For the CSS validatation there exist some errors [reported](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=andreas.galazis.com&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) but I don't think they are an issue.

Here is a [link](http://andreas.galazis.com/) to my website if you want to check the problem.

I would suggest to check it with java-script disabled as this reflects the state of the validated page.

The key point to this issue would be to figure out what changed in Chrome recently that caused this issue(since my code is validated but I might still be wrong). If you know where I can find change-logs about the rendering engine used let me know.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your exact problem is but my guess would be like yours that something has changed with the box model, you could always try using `box-sizing` which will push all your borders and padding inside the box instead of adding them to the outside of the box which will make it a little bit harder to break between browsers, you can apply this property like so

**CSS**

```
*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also I would suggest using a CSS reset which will reset all the default margins and padding's on elements, you will have to add your own margin's ect if you use that (CSS reset) but it will fix the problem with different browsers interpreting the default margins ect differently. Any ways hope this helps, and here's a link to a CSS reset, just add it in a separate stylesheet and link to it before your other stylesheets. Here's the link http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

PS: IE 9 and blow tend to have the most problems, but there is quick fixes out there that will help fix IE's problems for you, I would suggest this one here http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ and use the IE9 one.

**EDIT PLEASE READ !IMPORTANT**

Looked at your code and to fix your problem you'll need to remove the line `height: 48%` from the class `.midimage` on line 45 in `andreas.css` that will fix the flicking problem but you'll have to fix your position.

Comment: **It was  fixed using both box sizing code  and fixing the height Thank you for your answer. I will also look at some reset css as well as it is always helpful but the chrome problem is fixed for now :) I will mark this as the correct answer as it is complete and solved the problem.(not sure though why my site was getting away with the percentage height there in most other browsers and chrome itself beforehand)**

Comment: Glad to here you got it working, yeah I'm not to sure why that was affecting your site, but my guess would be is you have a few heights set that art actually targeting the same element, but I'd have to look more into it to verify that, glad it worked out! Nice site by the way its a little bit different than the usual site I see!